# Layout struggles with form - HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

I am fairly new to formatting in css. And I can't seem to find another question that is of similar layout to mine..
This is what I want it to look like:
[layout design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujJjM.png)

At the moment this is what I have:

```css
.RegisterBackground{
background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
float : none;
clear : both;
height : 400px;
width : 1000px;
margin-left:50px;
margin-top:50px;
margin-bottom:50px;

/* Makes div scrollable */
overflow-y: auto;
}

.blended_grid{
display : block;
width : 1100px;
overflow : auto;
margin : 0 auto;
}
*
{
border: 0;
margin: 0;
}
body{
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #666666;
    background:#3F3079;
    line-height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blended_grid">
<div class="RegisterBackground">
<form  action="" style="padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px;">
<label>Full Name: </label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" required  style="border: 1px solid black;">
<br/><br/>
<label>Phone Number:</label>
<input type="number" placeholder="Phone Number" required  style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
<br/><br/>
<label>Gender: </label>
<select name="cars  "style="border: 1px solid black;">
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<label>Birthday: </label>
<input type="date"  style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
<br/><br/>
<label>Type of Work: </label>
<select name="cars  "style="border: 1px solid black;">
  <option value="Fulltime">Full time</option>
  <option value="Parttime">Part time</option>
    <option value="Casual">Casual</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<label>Starting Date: </label>
<input type="date"  required  style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
<br/><br/>
<label>Annual leave left: </label>
<input type="number" placeholder="Current Annual Leave days left" required  style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
<br/><br/>


<div style="padding-right:500px; float:right">
<label>Login Details: </label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" required  style="border: 1px solid black;" > 
<br/><br/>
</div>
<div style="padding-right:500px; float:right">
<input type="text" placeholder="Password" required  style="border: 1px solid black;" > 
<br/><br/>
</div>
<div style="padding-right:500px; float:right">
<input type="text" placeholder="Confirm Password" required  style="border: 1px solid black;" > 
<br/><br/>
</div>
<div style="padding-right:500px; float:right">
<input type="text" placeholder="Confirm Password" required  style="border: 1px solid black;" > 
<br/><br/>
</div>


<label>Sick leave left: </label>
<input type="number" placeholder="Current Sick Leave days left" required  style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
<br/><br/>

<label>Staff ID number: </label>
<input type="number" placeholder="Staff ID number" required  style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
<br/><br/>



<label style="font-size:11px">Work days a week: </label>
<input type="number" placeholder="No. days work a week" required  style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
<br/><br/>

</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a working example below by using `display: table`, `display: table-row`, and `display: table-cell`. These work mostly like the HTML tags. There are responsive issues with this method that can be remedied by the use of media queries.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

body {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: #3F3079;
  font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #666666;
}

/* ************** Components ************** */

.blended-grid {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 50px;
}

.register-background {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 10px;
}

.form { display: table; }
.form-section { display: table-cell; }
.form-section-bottom { vertical-align: bottom; }
.form-section + .form-section { padding-left: 20px; }

.form-section-with-footer {
  position: relative; /* Help position: absolute below */
  padding-bottom: 50px; /* should at least be equal to footer height */
}

.form-section-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: right;
}

.form-group-header { font-size: 1.25em; }
.form-group { display: table; }
.form-control-wrapper { display: table-row; }
.form-control-wrapper + .form-control-wrapper > * { margin-top: 10px; }

.form-control-label {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.form-control {
  display: table-cell;
  min-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="blended-grid">
  <div class="register-background">
    <form class="" action="">
      <div class="form-section">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-control-wrapper">
            <label class="form-control-label">Full Name: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-control-wrapper">
            <label class="form-control-label">Phone Number:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-control-wrapper">
            <label class="form-control-label">Gender: </label>
            <select class="form-control" name="cars">
              <option value="male">Male</option>
              <option value="female">Female</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="form-control-wrapper">
            <label class="form-control-label">Birthday: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="date">
          </div>

          <div class="form-control-wrapper">
            <label class="form-control-label">Type of Work: </label>
            <select class="form-control" name="cars">
              <option value="Fulltime">Full time</option>
              <option value="Parttime">Part time</option>
              <option value="Casual">Casual</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="form-control-wrapper">
            <label class="form-control-label">Starting Date: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="date" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-control-wrapper">
            <label class="form-control-label">Annual leave left: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Current Annual Leave days left" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-control-wrapper">
            <label class="form-control-label">Sick leave left: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Current Sick Leave days left" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-control-wrapper">
            <label class="form-control-label">Staff ID number: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Staff ID number" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-control-wrapper">
            <label class="form-control-label">Work days a week: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="No. days work a week" required>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-section form-section-bottom">
        <h2 class="form-group-header">Login Details</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-control-wrapper">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-control-wrapper">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Password" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-control-wrapper">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-control-wrapper">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-section form-section-with-footer">
        <h2 class="form-group-header">Emergency Contact 1</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-control-wrapper">
            <label class="form-control-label">Full Name: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Full Name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-control-wrapper">
            <label class="form-control-label">Phone Number: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="form-group-header">Emergency Contact 2</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-control-wrapper">
            <label class="form-control-label">Full Name: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Full Name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-control-wrapper">
            <label class="form-control-label">Phone Number: </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-section-footer">
          <button>Register</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The other changes include removing all back-to-back `<br>` tags and any inline style tags. These are a code smell. With these removed, we can focus on keeping the styling in CSS.

Comment: I understand what you did there, and it worked like a charm! Thank you very much. I will remember to stay away from the <br> tags. It does make it look messier. 
Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I did the top several fields for you as an example.

Create a div for each column: wrap1, wrap2, wrap3.

Inside each of those, create a column of divs, each containing two other divs:

```
wrap1
    col1
        - leftside
        - rightside
    col1
        - leftside
        - rightside
```

Float:left the `leftside` and `rightside` divs. Floats have a height of zero, so to fix that, you must set their parent div to either `overflow:auto` or `overflow:hidden`

Use this same technique for the other two columns.

```css
div{position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;} /* pos:rel Req for bottom:0 to work */
.overall_wrap{overflow:hidden;border:1px solid purple;}
.overall_wrap div[class^=col]{margin:5px 0;}
.wrap1{float:left;width:30%;bottom:0;border:1px solid green;}
  .col1{width:100%;overflow:hidden;}
    .leftside{float:left;width:47%;padding-right:2%;text-align:right;}
    .rightside{float:left;width:49%;}

.wrap2{float:left;width:20%;bottom:0;text-align:center;overflow:visible;border:1px solid red;}
  .col2{width:100%;overflow:hidden;}

.wrap3{float:left;width:40%;top:0;border:1px solid blue;}
  .col3{width:100%;overflow:hidden;}
    .leftside{float:left;width:47%;padding-right:2%;text-align:right;}
    .rightside{float:left;width:49%;}
  .col3_lowerright{border:1px solid darkcyan;}
    .col3_lr-top{width:100%;height:20px;}
    .col3_lr-bot{width:100%;padding:20px;text-align:center;}
        #btnReg{padding:10px;border:1px solid orange;border-radius:5px;}

.RegisterBackground{
background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
float : none;
clear : both;
height : 400px;
width : 1000px;
margin-left:50px;
margin-top:50px;
margin-bottom:50px;

/* Makes div scrollable */
overflow-y: auto;
}

.blended_grid{
display : block;
width : 1100px;
overflow : auto;
margin : 0 auto;
}
*
{
border: 0;
margin: 0;
}
body{
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #666666;
    background:#3F3079;
    line-height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blended_grid">
 <div class="RegisterBackground">
  <form  action="" style="padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px;">
   <div class="overall_wrap">
    <div class="wrap1">
     <div class="col1">
      <div class="leftside">
       <label>Full Name: </label>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" required  style="border: 1px solid black;">
      </div>
     </div><!-- .col1 -->
     <div class="col1">
      <div class="leftside">
       <label>Phone Number:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
       <input type="number" placeholder="Phone Number" required  style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
      </div>
     </div><!-- .col1 -->
     <div class="col1">
      <div class="leftside">
       <label>Gender: </label>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
       <select name="cars  "style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
       </select>
      </div>
     </div><!-- .col1 -->
     <div class="col1">
      <div class="leftside">
       <label>Birthday: </label>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
       <input type="date"  style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
      </div>
     </div><!-- .col1 -->
     <div class="col1">
      <div class="leftside">
       <label>Type of Work: </label>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
       <select name="cars  "style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <option value="Fulltime">Full time</option>
        <option value="Parttime">Part time</option>
        <option value="Casual">Casual</option>
       </select>
      </div>
     </div><!-- .col1 -->
     <div class="col1">
      <div class="leftside">
       <label>Starting Date: </label>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
       <input type="date"  required  style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
      </div>
     </div><!-- .col1 -->
     <div class="col1">
      <div class="leftside">
       <label>Annual leave left: </label>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
       <input type="number" placeholder="Current Annual Leave days left" required  style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
      </div>
     </div><!-- .col1 -->
     <div class="col1">
      <div class="leftside">
       <label>Sick leave left: </label>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
       <input type="number" placeholder="Current Sick Leave days left" required  style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
      </div>
     </div><!-- .col1 -->
     <div class="col1">
      <div class="leftside">
       <label>Staff ID number: </label>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
       <input type="number" placeholder="Staff ID number" required  style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
      </div>
     </div><!-- .col1 -->
     <div class="col1">
      <div class="leftside">
       <label style="font-size:11px">Work days a week: </label>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
       <input type="number" placeholder="No. days work a week" required  style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
      </div>
     </div><!-- .col1 -->
    </div><!-- .wrap1 -->

    <div class="wrap2">
     <div class="col2">
      <label>Login Details: </label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required  style="border: 1px solid black;" > 
     </div>
     <div class="col2">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Password" required  style="border: 1px solid black;" > 
     </div>
     <div class="col2">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Confirm Password" required  style="border: 1px solid black;" > 
     </div>
     <div class="col2">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Confirm Password" required  style="border: 1px solid black;" > 
     </div>
    </div><!-- .wrap2 -->


    <div class="wrap3">
     <div class="col3">
      <div class="leftside">
       <p>&nbsp;</p>
       <label style="font-size:11px">Full Name: </label>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
       Emergency Contact 1
       <input type="number" placeholder="Full Name" required  style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
      </div>
     </div><!-- .col3 -->
     <div class="col3">
      <div class="leftside">
       <label style="font-size:11px">Phone Number: </label>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
       <input type="number" placeholder="Phone Number" required  style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
      </div>
     </div><!-- .col3 -->

     <p>&nbsp;</p>

     <div class="col3">
      <div class="leftside">
       <p>&nbsp;</p>
       <label style="font-size:11px">Full Name: </label>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
       Emergency Contact 2
       <input type="number" placeholder="Full Name" required  style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
      </div>
     </div><!-- .col3 -->
     <div class="col3">
      <div class="leftside">
       <label style="font-size:11px">Phone Number: </label>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
       <input type="number" placeholder="Phone Number" required  style="border: 1px solid black;"> 
      </div>
     </div><!-- .col3 -->
     <div class="col3_lowerright">
      <div class="col3_lr-top"></div>
      <div class="col3_lr-bot">
       <button id="btnReg">Register</button>
      </div>
     </div><!-- .col3_lowerright -->
    </div><!-- .wrap3 -->
   </div><!-- .overall_wrap -->
  </form>
 </div><!-- .RegisterBackground -->
</div><!-- .blended_grid -->
```

---

Updated to do a bit more. You'll have to solve the col2 stick at bottom yourself as I'm out of time. Here's how it works:

`position:static` is the default, but it will not allow top/bottom/left/right (e.g. `top:15px`)
`position:relative` allows top/bottom/left/right

Use `position:relative;bottom:0;` to align a div at bottom of parent div

I am unsure how `float:left` interferes/interacts with `bottom:0`

You might also need to explore the flexbox model, which is extremely helpful and finally ready for use.

http://www.webdesignermag.co.uk/responsive-layouts-with-flexbox/

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your comment. Could you please clarify what you mean by adding different columns? I had a go at creating like col2 etc. And implementing that. 
-The first column looks great, but I still cannot manage to get the second column to align properly next to col1. - like in my image I attached - Can you see it? Thanks

Comment: Updated answer. Trust you can take it from there..? If further issues, please create a new question with just that one question.